# crop image in reactjs using html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas, crop

I am trying to crop an image in reactjs without using any library.First the user will upload image and the user will crop the image using raw js and replace the uploaded image.How can i do it without using any library.I want to use the crop component somthing like this in reactjs[reference](http://jsfiddle.net/Tatarize/w1Lh4w2t/).For me html cansvas seems to be not working how can i do it using html canvas?this is the sandbox link:[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-hill-w6w0e?file=/src/App.js)

this is the code i did for showing image:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class ReactCrop extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            file: null,
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)


    }
    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            file: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])
        })
        console.log("ok",this.state.file)
    }


    saveCroped() {
        const width = 500;
        const height = 300;
        const fileName = e.target.files[0].name;
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
        reader.onload = event => {
            const img = new Image();
            img.src = event.target.result;
            img.onload = () => {
                const elem = document.createElement('canvas');
                elem.width = width;
                elem.height = height;
                const ctx = elem.getContext('2d');
                // img.width and img.height will contain the original dimensions
                ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
                ctx.canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
                    const file = new File([blob], fileName, {
                        type: 'image/jpeg',
                        lastModified: Date.now()
                    });
                }, 'image/jpeg', 1);
            },
                reader.onerror = error => console.log(error);
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('componentDidMount colling ...');

    }
    render() {

        return (
            <div className="app">
                <div style={{width:'450px', margin:'0 auto'}}>
                    <label htmlFor="file" style={{paddingRight:'80px',marginLeft:'-10px'}}>
                        <input id="files"   type="file" style={{border:'0px',paddingBottom:'12px'}}   key={this.state.inputKey}
                               onChange={this.handleChange}  type="file"/>
                    </label>
                    {this.state.file === null?
                        <p></p>
                        : <img style={{width:'362px',height:'365px',paddingTop:'10px',marginRight:'85px'}} onClick={this.rotate} src={this.state.file}/>

                    }
                </div>
                <button type="button" onClick={() => {this.saveCroped()}}>crop</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ReactCrop;
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. Here is a working example: (it wont download in online sandbox, but works fine on independent branches e.g. localhost, see console messages) [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-hofstadter-wunfp?file=/src/App.js)

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Crop = function(){
    const canvas = useRef();
    const file = useRef();
    
    const preview = useRef();
    const [imageParams, setImageParams] = useState();
    const [context, setContext] = useState();


    // Initialize
    useEffect(function(){

        file.current.onchange = onNewImage;
        setContext( canvas.current.getContext('2d') );

    },[])

    // Draw image on imageParams Change
    useEffect(function(){
        if(!imageParams) return;
        
        context.drawImage( preview.current, 0, 0, imageParams.width*(700/imageParams.height), 700 )
        
    }, [imageParams])

    // Get with and height, replace preview, set params
    function onNewImage(){
        const newImgUrl = URL.createObjectURL( file.current.files[0] );
        const newImage = document.createElement('img');

        newImage.setAttribute('src', newImgUrl);

        newImage.onload = function(){
            const {width, height} = newImage;
            const type = file.current.files[0].type

            newImage.setAttribute('width', '50px');

            preview.current.parentElement.append(newImage);
            preview.current.remove();

            preview.current = newImage;

            setImageParams({ width, height, type });
        }
    }

    // Save image on click
    function handleSave(){

        canvas.current.toBlob(function(blob){
            
            const anchor = document.createElement('a');

            anchor.innerHTML = 'download';

            anchor.download = "my_file."+imageParams.type.replace(/^.{1,}\//,'');

            anchor.href = (window.webkitURL || window.URL).createObjectURL(blob);
            anchor.dataset.downloadurl = [imageParams.type, anchor.download, anchor.href].join(':');
            anchor.click();

            preview.current.parentElement.append(anchor);

        }, imageParams.type);

    }

    return <>
        <div className="input">
            
            <input 
                ref={file}
                type="file"
                accept="image/png, image/jpeg" />

            <div
                style={{width:"100px", display: 'inline-block'}}>
                <img
                    
                    ref={preview}
                    />
            </div>
            

            <button 
                onClick={handleSave} >save image</button>

        </div>

        <div class="canvas">
            <canvas 
                ref={canvas}
                width='700px'
                height='700px' />
        </div>  

    </>;
}

export default Crop;
```

Comment: is it  possible to make an aspect ratio and moving the mouse around in the area i want to crop?

Comment: Sure, as you may have mentioned we draw image to context based on the fact we've previously set canvas to 700 by 700. `context.drawImage( preview.current, 0, 0, imageParams.width*(700/imageParams.height), 700 )` meaning `context.drawImage( image, starTop, startLeft, width*renderedAspectRatio, canvasHeight )`; So if you set canvas to a different size ratio and render image to canvas accordingly you can render pretty much any part of the image in any size. To implement interactive crop functionality you would set some moving resizable div and redraw image to canvas on every resize end event.